# How can I prevent websites that use a Google Account login to log me out after a while of inactivity?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-accounts

I observed that some websites that use a Google Account login, such as [ShoutEngine](http://shoutengine.com/) or [Zendesk](https://www.zendesk.com/), log me out of the session after a certain while of inactivity.

Is there any way to configure my default web browser Google Chrome to prevent this logout and constantly remain logged in?

With extensions such as [Staying Alive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/staying-alive-for-google/lhobbakbeomfcgjallalccfhfcgleinm) I can keep the session active during the same browser session. However, as soon as I restart my machine and reopen Chrome, I need to login again.

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: The inactivity timer won't be related to your log-in account. You may like to look at the [**Staying Alive** extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/staying-alive-for-google/lhobbakbeomfcgjallalccfhfcgleinm).

Comment: Thanks! This only works during the active session but whenever I restart Chrome, I need to log in again. Is there any extension to prevent this, too? See my edits to the question.

Comment: I doubt it. Logging you off after inactivity is a security measure implemented for your protection. If you exit and restart within the time-out period, you may find you'll still be logged in. Some web-sites, like Amazon, have a "keep me logged in" option when you log in; web-sites without this option will log you out. Since you are logging in with your Google account, this should be only a click or two, provided that you have set "keep me logged in" in your Google account.